# Scraping a website with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a website with BeautifulSoup. More specifically I'm trying to get the string from a following tag:

```
<td class="Fz(s) Fw(500) Ta(end)" data-reactid=".17c0h26fqwq.1.$0.0.0.3.1.$main-0-Quote-Proxy.$main 0-Quote.2.0.0.0.1.0.0:$VALUATION_MEASURES.0.1.0.$MARKET_CAP_INTRADAY.1">4.39B</td>
```

However, when I try to look for the attrs of all td tags, BeautifulSoup can't find the one I want. This is the code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
source_code = urlopen('http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/IONS/key-statistics?p=IONS').read()
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
yahoo_finance = BeautifulSoup(source_code, 'html.parser')
tds = yahoo_finance.find_all('td')
for td in tds:
    print(td.attrs)
```

This is the output:

```
{'class': ['W(100%)', 'Va(t)', 'Px(0)'], 'data-reactid': '.odbtogw33w.0.0.$uh.2.0.1.0.1.0.0.0'}
{'class': ['Va(t)', 'Tren(os)', 'W(10%)', 'Whs(nw)', 'Px(0)', 'Bdcl(s)'], 'data-reactid': '.odbtogw33w.0.0.$uh.2.0.1.0.1.0.0.1'}
```

So, it doesn't find 'class':['Fz(s)', 'Fw(500)', 'Ta(end)']

Does anyone have an idea why?

Goran

Comment: look at the source returned and you will see why

Comment: The tag you're looking for doesn't appear in the source, at least not when I fetch the URL you mentioned.  If you've seen it in your browser, perhaps it's because it only gets included in the page based on a particular request context, like a session cookie?  In that case, you'd have to match whatever condition is required in the request sent from your script.

Comment: @nephtes, it has nothing to do with cookies, it is dynamically generated content

Comment: How do I capture such content then?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham well, yes, that's what I meant by "based on a particular request context".  The question is, what are the conditions which cause that particular tag to be included in the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the data just using requests, the content is generated from an ajax get to *https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/IONS*:

```
from pprint import pprint as pp
import requests

params = {"formatted": "true", "lang": "en-US", "region": "US",
          "modules": "defaultKeyStatistics,financialData,calendarEvents", "corsDomain": "finance.yahoo.com"}

url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/IONS/key-statistics?p=IONS"
ajax = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/IONS"

with requests.Session() as s:
    cont = requests.get(url).content
    data = s.get(ajax, params=params).json()

    pp(data[u'quoteSummary']["result"])
```

That gives you:

```
[{u'calendarEvents': {u'dividendDate': {},
                      u'earnings': {u'earningsAverage': {u'fmt': u'-0.53',
                                                         u'raw': -0.53},
                                    u'earningsDate': [{u'fmt': u'2016-08-09',
                                                       u'raw': 1470700800}],
                                    u'earningsHigh': {u'fmt': u'-0.39',
                                                      u'raw': -0.39},
                                    u'earningsLow': {u'fmt': u'-0.75',
                                                     u'raw': -0.75},
                                    u'revenueAverage': {u'fmt': u'37.69M',
                                                        u'longFmt': u'37,690,000',
                                                        u'raw': 37690000},
                                    u'revenueHigh': {u'fmt': u'56M',
                                                     u'longFmt': u'56,000,000',
                                                     u'raw': 56000000},
                                    u'revenueLow': {u'fmt': u'25.2M',
                                                    u'longFmt': u'25,200,000',
                                                    u'raw': 25200000}},
                      u'exDividendDate': {},
                      u'maxAge': 1},
  u'defaultKeyStatistics': {u'52WeekChange': {u'fmt': u'\u221e%',
                                              u'raw': u'Infinity'},
                            u'SandP52WeekChange': {u'fmt': u'3.65%',
                                                   u'raw': 0.03645599},
                            u'annualHoldingsTurnover': {},
                            u'annualReportExpenseRatio': {},
                            u'beta': {u'fmt': u'2.35', u'raw': 2.35046},
                            u'beta3Year': {},
                            u'bookValue': {u'fmt': u'1.31', u'raw': 1.31},
                            u'category': None,
                            u'earningsQuarterlyGrowth': {},
                            u'enterpriseToEbitda': {u'fmt': u'-37.62',
                                                    u'raw': -37.618},
                            u'enterpriseToRevenue': {u'fmt': u'15.86',
                                                     u'raw': 15.864},
                            u'enterpriseValue': {u'fmt': u'4.09B',
                                                 u'longFmt': u'4,092,714,240',
                                                 u'raw': 4092714240},
                            u'fiveYearAverageReturn': {},
                            u'floatShares': {u'fmt': u'119.83M',
                                             u'longFmt': u'119,833,635',
                                             u'raw': 119833635},
                            u'forwardEps': {u'fmt': u'-1.14', u'raw': -1.14},
                            u'forwardPE': {u'fmt': u'-31.87',
                                           u'raw': -31.868423},
                            u'fundFamily': None,
                            u'fundInceptionDate': {},
                            u'heldPercentInsiders': {},
                            u'heldPercentInstitutions': {},
                            u'lastCapGain': {},
                            u'lastDividendValue': {},
                            u'lastFiscalYearEnd': {u'fmt': u'2015-12-31',
                                                   u'raw': 1451520000},
                            u'lastSplitDate': {},
                            u'lastSplitFactor': None,
                            u'legalType': None,
                            u'maxAge': 1,
                            u'morningStarOverallRating': {},
                            u'morningStarRiskRating': {},
                            u'mostRecentQuarter': {u'fmt': u'2016-03-31',
                                                   u'raw': 1459382400},
                            u'netIncomeToCommon': {u'fmt': u'-134.48M',
                                                   u'longFmt': u'-134,478,000',
                                                   u'raw': -134478000},
                            u'nextFiscalYearEnd': {u'fmt': u'2017-12-31',
                                                   u'raw': 1514678400},
                            u'pegRatio': {u'fmt': u'-0.76', u'raw': -0.76},
                            u'priceToBook': {u'fmt': u'27.73',
                                             u'raw': 27.732826},
                            u'priceToSalesTrailing12Months': {},
                            u'profitMargins': {u'fmt': u'-52.12%',
                                               u'raw': -0.52124},
                            u'revenueQuarterlyGrowth': {},
                            u'sharesOutstanding': {u'fmt': u'120.78M',
                                                   u'longFmt': u'120,783,000',
                                                   u'raw': 120783000},
                            u'sharesShort': {u'fmt': u'13.89M',
                                             u'longFmt': u'13,890,400',
                                             u'raw': 13890400},
                            u'sharesShortPriorMonth': {u'fmt': u'13.03M',
                                                       u'longFmt': u'13,032,400',
                                                       u'raw': 13032400},
                            u'shortPercentOfFloat': {u'fmt': u'13.66%',
                                                     u'raw': 0.13664},
                            u'shortRatio': {u'fmt': u'6.66', u'raw': 6.66},
                            u'threeYearAverageReturn': {},
                            u'totalAssets': {},
                            u'trailingEps': {u'fmt': u'-1.12',
                                             u'raw': -1.119},
                            u'yield': {},
                            u'ytdReturn': {}},
  u'financialData': {u'currentPrice': {u'fmt': u'36.33', u'raw': 36.33},
                     u'currentRatio': {u'fmt': u'6.14', u'raw': 6.136},
                     u'debtToEquity': {u'fmt': u'302.79', u'raw': 302.793},
                     u'earningsGrowth': {},
                     u'ebitda': {u'fmt': u'-108.8M',
                                 u'longFmt': u'-108,796,000',
                                 u'raw': -108796000},
                     u'ebitdaMargins': {u'fmt': u'-42.17%',
                                        u'raw': -0.42169997},
                     u'freeCashflow': {u'fmt': u'15.13M',
                                       u'longFmt': u'15,127,875',
                                       u'raw': 15127875},
                     u'grossMargins': {u'fmt': u'-30.48%', u'raw': -0.30478},
                     u'grossProfits': {u'fmt': u'283.7M',
                                       u'longFmt': u'283,703,000',
                                       u'raw': 283703000},
                     u'maxAge': 86400,
                     u'numberOfAnalystOpinions': {u'fmt': u'8',
                                                  u'longFmt': u'8',
                                                  u'raw': 8},
                     u'operatingCashflow': {u'fmt': u'-11.82M',
                                            u'longFmt': u'-11,817,000',
                                            u'raw': -11817000},
                     u'operatingMargins': {u'fmt': u'-46.09%',
                                           u'raw': -0.46085998},
                     u'profitMargins': {u'fmt': u'-52.12%',
                                        u'raw': -0.52124},
                     u'quickRatio': {u'fmt': u'5.94', u'raw': 5.944},
                     u'recommendationKey': u'hold',
                     u'recommendationMean': {u'fmt': u'2.80', u'raw': 2.8},
                     u'returnOnAssets': {u'fmt': u'-8.12%',
                                         u'raw': -0.08116},
                     u'returnOnEquity': {u'fmt': u'-61.97%',
                                         u'raw': -0.6197},
                     u'revenueGrowth': {u'fmt': u'-41.10%', u'raw': -0.411},
                     u'revenuePerShare': {u'fmt': u'2.15', u'raw': 2.148},
                     u'targetHighPrice': {u'fmt': u'64.00', u'raw': 64.0},
                     u'targetLowPrice': {u'fmt': u'17.00', u'raw': 17.0},
                     u'targetMeanPrice': {u'fmt': u'39.13', u'raw': 39.13},
                     u'targetMedianPrice': {u'fmt': u'38.00', u'raw': 38.0},
                     u'totalCash': {u'fmt': u'723.51M',
                                    u'longFmt': u'723,507,008',
                                    u'raw': 723507008},
                     u'totalCashPerShare': {u'fmt': u'5.99', u'raw': 5.99},
                     u'totalDebt': {u'fmt': u'478.9M',
                                    u'longFmt': u'478,904,000',
                                    u'raw': 478904000},
                     u'totalRevenue': {u'fmt': u'257.99M',
                                       u'longFmt': u'257,993,984',
                                       u'raw': 257993984}}}]
```

Comment: Is there any list of all the possible modules that I can use under params variable?

Answer (score 0):

So this is additional code that I wrote, now I can nicely save dynamically generated content and get the tag that I want with BeautifulSoup:

```
from contextlib import closing
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

with closing(Firefox()) as browser:
    browser.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/IONS?p=IONS')
    button = browser.find_element_by_link_text('Statistics')
    button.click()
    #WebDriverWait(browser, timeout=10).until(
        #lambda x: x.find_element_by_class_name('Fz(s) Fw(500) Ta(end)'))
    page_source = browser.page_source
print(page_source)

yahoo_finance = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')
```

@nephtes @Padraic Cunningham thanks for hints.